# Shut down or suspend laptop for night?

Tags: shutdown

Just a simple question, should I suspend or shut down my laptop for night (~8 hours), considering that I don't care about power consumption?

In Windows I would usually make it sleep because of how long it takes to boot, but since Ubuntu boots so quickly in comparison I can just shut down it if it's better for laptop.

Comment: If you don't worry about power consumption, leave it turned on. If you want to have all the apps open the next day, suspend, else shutdown. This is really opinion-based.

Comment: @Helio - if that's only opinion based it should be a more clear answer explaining why. Does Linux/Ubuntu need shutdown or not? -  that is the question.  - The question is whether Linux/Ubuntu imposes a necessary action on the matter or not.

Comment: @cipricus: Linux doesn't *need* shutdown (AFAIK), however I shutdown my computer every night.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a matter of taste. I shut down to save on energy bills, but honestly, I would shut down my Ubuntu systems anyway, since they are so quick to boot.

Comment: Yeah, my question is just what is better for laptop itself.

Comment: If there is any power drain at all, such as in Suspend, just make sure it is plugged in. If you can't or don't want to plug it in, then Shut Down. Hibernate is also a good alternative to Shut Down if not plugged in. On a laptop that is regularly in use, it is best to keep the battery on full charge as much as possible.

Comment: it's not a matter of taste and this should not have been closed. most windows users shut down often. [apple users do not have to shut down over night (daily use)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/128153/61618): what about ubuntu/linux?