# Better to suspend my ubuntu or shut down it during long journey in car?

Tags: suspend, shutdown

I will be in a 4hr car drive, but I still have a lot of unfinished editing jobs that I don't want to close in Ubuntu, because I will have to take notes of what is left for each job so that I can resume it.

shall I suspend Ubuntu, or shut it down, for data and laptop safety during the long car drive?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not really a technical support issue and will be closed, it is really up to you and your needs, all anyone can offer is opinion.

Comment: @Mark Kirby: I've seen many questions like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/378176/shut-down-or-suspend-laptop-for-night?rq=1. I'm afraid deleting them is all for nothing. People will keep on asking. New people to Ubuntu happening everyday. Better new to Ubuntu than new to Windows, don't you think?

Comment: @ipselute It is not about that, there are specific reasons we close questions and one of them is that it is a matter of opinion, there is a whole close reason dedicated to this. Answers that are just opinion have no real value, they may not be right for the next person that comes along. As for the other question, I voted to close it too.

Comment: @ipselute I will tell you where exactly this kind of question will be welcome though http://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: @MarkKirby: I know you're right. Let's kindly ask inquirers to look for opinions, NOT answers, there. I myself am a member of Ubuntu forum since 2006, but i'm not using it much (maybe once a year, shame on me!), because it's so big and i have to browse through a ton of topics to find anything useful. AskUbuntu is so simple, just drop a question and see what happens. Short answers, not endless topics. That's why  i like AskUbuntu so much.

Comment: @ipselute Thats why I like it on here :) Quick and to the point. Forums can be good too, on Ubuntu forums, the OP could have a full discussion about it and that would be better for them than 10 opinions posted here IMO.

Comment: @ipselute I like the idea of directing these users to ubuntu forums, I made a request to add it to the close reason http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15455/add-ubuntu-forums-link-to-opinion-close-reason

Answer (score 1):

Maybe shut down and take a nap. Suspend will still keep some software in RAM memory, thus eating some battery. Probably not much, but enough to make a difference in some situations. That's for laptops.
If you're planning to take notes on an Ubuntu tablet or convertible, i see no reason to shut down. God, i wish i'd have a Galaxy tablet with Ubuntu on it!